# Último registro relacionado

Tags: postgresql

Tengo una base de datos en Postgres con  2 tablas relacionadas así:

```
TBL_PREDIOS
=============
predio_codigo
predio_nombre

TBL_AREAS
=========
area_id
area_anio
predio_codigo
```

Cada predio puede tener varias áreas, pero necesito obtener la última área (el id mas alto) y la información relacionada (es decir el area_anio y el area_id) para cada predio, pero todos los predios.

La idea es crear con esta consulta una vista que contenga la última area para cada predio y poder hacer un inner join a esa vista desde otra consulta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nose si te entiendo muy bien. pero podrías hacer esto:

```
    Select predio_codigo,predrio_nombre,area_id,area_anio 
    from tbl_predios tp
    Inner join tbl_areas ta on ta.predio_codigo=tp.codigo and 
    area_id in (select max(area_id) from tbl_areas group by predio_codigo)
```

Comment: Me entendiste bien. Funciona para mi esta consulta. Muchas gracias!!